# Always connect test database on mongodb with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have studied on mongodb with spring boot

I install mongo with docker-compose, I use Mongo Compass to interactive with mongo database, and I create product database

```bash
version: "3.8"
services:
    mongodb:
        image : mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
        - PUID=1000
        - PGID=1000
        volumes:
        - ./database/product-service/mongodb:/data/db
        ports:
        - 27017:27017
        restart: unless-stopped
```

Spring Boot code

Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createProduct(@RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest) {
        productService.createProduct(productRequest);
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ProductResponse> getAllProducts() {
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }
}
```

Service

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ProductService {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    public void createProduct(ProductRequest productRequest) {
        Product product = Product.builder()
                .name(productRequest.getName())
                .description(productRequest.getDescription())
                .price(productRequest.getPrice())
                .build();
        productRepository.save(product);
        log.info("Product {} is saved", product.getId());
    }

    public List<ProductResponse> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product>products = productRepository.findAll();
        log.info("Get all products");
        return products.stream().map(product -> map2ProductResponse(product)).toList();
    }

    private ProductResponse map2ProductResponse(Product product) {
        return ProductResponse.builder()
                .id(product.getId())
                .name(product.getName())
                .description(product.getDescription())
                .price(product.getPrice())
                .build();
    }
}
```

entity

```java
@Document(value = "product")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

With spring boot app, I configed on appllication.properties file like that

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/product
```

Because I have found some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750815/how-to-specify-database-name-in-spring-data-mongodb)

I have tried replace with this, nothing change

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=product
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

when I check the Mongo Compass, it always connect to **test** database, although I specify **product** database like application.properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8V5A.png)

I have also found the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537715/spring-boot-and-mongodb-always-connect-to-database-test), I have tried with that solution, it not working for me and the solution is too complicated for me. It raise a error

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
```

And I can not fix that problem, because I'm new with mongo

How I can change spring boot app connect to another database?

Comment: Are you sure you 100% sure you have a `product` database? From the image you uploaded it doesn't look like you have a `product` database. Just the `test` database with `product` collection.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I miss. After install mongo database, I use MongoDB Compass to create manually product database

Comment: Looks like spring/docker problem (not mongo). 
After running docker compose mongo, try to reach mongo from cli. Here is link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongocli/v1.28/install/  . If you can connect to mongo through cli, it means that docker/network setup is ok.
Second thing that comes to mind is removing spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/product from application.properties. Use uri OR other props like host+port+database.

Comment: thanks, I have tried to connect to mongo from cli and it worked correctly, I use mongosh **docker exec -it mongodb mongosh**. second, I have tried like that as i said before I post the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to read mongo for a couple hours [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/auth/), I have found the solution.

Almost of authentication mechanisms, we can not set database name

For example with default authentication mechanism using connection string or mongo credential, I don't see the parameter for database name, only include **username**, **authenticationDb**, and **password**

With connection string:

```java
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients
.create("mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/?authSource=<authenticationDb>");
```

With MongoCredential:

```java
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("<username>", "<authenticationDb>", "<password>");
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(
    MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("<hostname>", <port>))))
        .credential(credential)
        .build());
```

Other mechanisms are same.

Thus, I have tried to create config file

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoDBConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:pass12345@127.0.0.1:27018");
    }
}
```

and add database name in application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=product
```

Its amazing, it work perfectly like I want

Comment: Just as note: if there is no authentication involved, then simply remove the username and password part.  ex. return MongoClients.create("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have database and collection name same as "product". Try different naming for database and collection for standardization.

For connecting to product database from your java code, you could write a configuration class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")` with a bean for `MongoClient` like this

```java
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(getConnectionString());
}
```

You can build the connectionString from your `application.properties` like this:

```java
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("mongodb://");
sb.append(getDBUsername(dbUserName));
sb.append(":");
sb.append(getDBPasswordByPath(dbPassword));
sb.append("@");
sb.append(getHost());
sb.append(":");
sb.append(getPort());
sb.append("/");
sb.append(getDbName());
sb.append("?retrywrites=false");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although your answer is not exactly what I expect, but I have also tried with mongo config. And the problem is not still resolve, it always connect to test databases